# {{$timestamp}} returning 1970 time not current time

Tags: json, mongodb, timestamp, httprequest, postman

According to the [documentation in Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox#dynamic-variables) a current time/date (in milliseconds) can be inserted into the body request by using `{{$timestamp}}` but this is just returning the 1970 milliseconds for me as I can see when querying the database directly. The data is passed into a MongoDB which accepts JSON entries like so and converts it into an ISO date:

```
  {
    "adminModifiedId" : 1,
    "dateCreated" : { "$date": {{$timestamp}}},
    "lastModified" : { "$date": {{$timestamp}}},
    "adminCreatedId" : 1
  }
```

The `ISODate` as seen directly in the database is `ISODate("1970-01-18T20:45:01.406Z")`. Does anyone have any experience with this issue or a solve? thanks all!

Comment: *"the 1970 milliseconds"* – meaning *0*?

Comment: @deceze thanks - I've updated the question as I see the time as an `ISODate`. When returning it in *Postman* it is in JSON format: `"dateCreated": { "$date": 1543501675 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that postman [$timestamp](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/variables) returns epoch seconds, where as a `new Date()` in mongo accepts it in epoch milliseconds (same as javascript)

You could handle it in the server side by multiplying by 1000.

If you want it to be handled in postman, it can be done using postman variables created in the "Pre-request". (See [Link](http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/12/29/10-tips-for-working-with-postman-variables/) for detailed info.)

```
let t = Date.now()
pm.environment.set('t', t);
```

[image]

Now you can refer to this variable in your request body by simply surrounding it in curly braces.

```
{
   "date": {{t}}
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know about the epoch seconds being returned. Just a slight alteration I've made with the curly brackets and having tested; it does work. If there isn't a `$timestamp` shortcut that returns epoch milliseconds then I'll mark this as the best answer. Good catch!

Comment: I rewrote the answer now, after researching more on this. I'm glad I came across this question, as I learned a really cool ability of the postman tool. So thanks for asking this question :)

Comment: That seems like a good solution! Although I am slightly confused as in the environment settings; I can see default globals are already set including `now`, `timestampUtcIso8601` & `timestampheader`. I can only access `timestamp` so the others must be in the wrong format. As I'm always using *MongoDB* and therefore entries are always `JSON` - it does seem that I should make the the `t` variable as a global variable across all environments. But perhaps this isn't possible.